# sfml sf::Image() class issues

Tags: c++, xcode, image, shared-libraries, sfml

So I'm using the sfml frameworks in an XCode project I'm building and I'm having some trouble with the sf::Image() class.

Some of the functions work perfectly fine and as expected, but others give compiler errors.

For example, I can do the following with no errors and it'll print the correct result:

```
sf::Image *image = new sf::Image(600,600);
int width = image->GetWidth();
int height = image->GetHeight();
std::cout<<width<<" "<<height<<std::endl;
```

So I know the library is being at least somewhat integrated. However, functions like SaveToFile() and LoadFromFile() give me compiler errors. For example, if I do the following I get an "using undefined symbols for this architecture" error.

```
std::string filename = "myfile.jpg";
sf::Image *image = new sf::Image(600,600);
image->SaveToFile(filename);
```

I appreciate any and all help!

Comment: Have you tried using image.SaveToFile(filename) to see if that works?

Comment: Please upgrade to 2.0. SFML 1.x versions are all deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

Are the SFML dll besides your EXE in your Debug directory?

In my own project, there's 3 dll from SFML which are:

- sfml-graphics-2.dll
- sfml-system-2.dll
- sfml-window-2.dll

Which can be found in the SFML Bin directory. Also, don't forget add the SFML > lib dir to the Library Search Path of your project. Again, don't forget to use the appropriate lib:

- sfml-graphics
- sfml-window
- sfml-system
- opengl32